# Show vertical borders for each child view in a ListView row

Tags: android, listview

I have seen examples of ListView where each row has multiple view objects, like a TextView and a Button or 2 TextViews, etc. I want to have 3 TextView objects per row, and a vertical border between them, and 4 such rows, so that the ListView resembles a 3 by 4 grid with cell borders. Is it possible?

I need 2 solutions: one, using a ListView with borders as described above; two, using any other appropriate layout or viewgroup like GridView or TableLayout.

Please give sample code.

Thanks.

Comment: Your "give the code" attitude, requesting two different solutions, without even showing what you tried, is not very good. You should at least show some research you might have done before blatantly going and asking for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android a ListView can use custom xml to define each row.
A simple example of a custom row from an array would be just
`setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row_xml, sourceArray));` where `list_row_xml.xml` defines how each row looks.
There is a tutorial 
[here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) which shows you how to use more advanced custom rows. Specifically you're looking for his `row.xml` code.
Hope that helps